# How to get Discord.js bot to log variable for every user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot similar to Pokecord and would like to log 1 or more variables for every user. I am using Discord.js, JavaScript, and Node.js.
Is this possible?

Comment: what did you mean for log 1 or more variables for every user? you mean log to console every user using your bot?

Comment: @R4y What I mean is to store (for now) one number for every user, which can be edited by typing "!money add 1" for example. (That command would add 1 to the users variable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not work, I don't have time or resources to test but its code salvaged from a previous project

```
var money = new Map();
const mems = client.guilds.get("serverid"); 

mems.members.forEach(member => () {
     money.set(member.user.username, 1);
     console.log(money.get(member.user.username));
});
```

Comment: Losing all data if the bot restarts. I don't know if it happens, though. At least if you update it, no? Might or might not be a problem, depending on nature of data.

Comment: You will lose any data that gets set to a variable or any other data type in your script if you don't save it. You can save the maps values into a JSON file with node.js then load them again when your script reloads (bot logs back on)

Answer (score 1):

To store a certain value or variable for each user, you have three main options. A database is probably your best choice.

### 1. Declaring a `Map`

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for more about Maps in JavaScript.

**Pros**
- Simple and easy
- Contained completely within your code

**Cons**
- All values will be reset if the code stops

**Example**
When initializing your client, you can declare one of its properties as a Map, so you can easily access it elsewhere in your code:

```js
client.money = new Map();
```

Retrieving a user's balance:

```js
const ID = message.author.id; // or set it as the mentioned user's ID, etc.
console.log(client.money.get(ID));
```

Setting a user's balance:

```js
client.money.set(ID, 5);
```

Adding to a user's balance:

```js
client.money.set(ID, client.money.get(ID) + 2);
```

### 2. json File

**Pros**
- Separate file/organized
- Stays even after code stops running

**Cons**
- Slightly more complicated
- Speed, compared to DB

**Example**
`money.json`:

```
{ "userIDhere": 0 }
```

Retrieving a user's balance:

```js
const money = require('./money.json'); // path may vary
const ID = message.author.id; // or set it as the mentioned user's ID, etc.
console.log(money[ID]);
```

Setting a user's balance:

```js
money[ID] = 3;
fs.writeFileSync('./money.json', JSON.stringify(money));
```

Adding to a user's balance:

```js
money[ID] += 8;
fs.writeFileSync('./money.json', JSON.stringify(money));
```

### 3. Database

**Pros**
- Speed
- Stays even after code stops running
- Easily accessible

**Cons**
- Harder setup

Your choice for a database is up to you, and setup and usage vary for each. Do some research for which is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use my SQL databe installed in a server and then add phpmyadmin and you have just to connect to your database

Answer (score 0):

well this isn't very easy, for this you must create a database i suggest you
[Mysql](https://dbotmaker.io/forums/threads/how-to-mysql-with-dbm-guide.645/) install that and then watch the guide another cool guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGZX_SA7lYg)
then if you installed and watched the guides
`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'myhost',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'myuser'
  password : 'mypassword',
  database : 'mydatabase',
  charset : 'utf8mb4'
});
```

this to connect and then you have to create a value(money) in a database and assign a the value you want

```
bot.on('!money add 1', message => {
 //get the database and add a variable with the username and the value of money you want

});
```

Comment: Invalid options (missing string ending in user field), invalid event syntax.

Comment: Probably u have missed to install mysql or some data in login try type in console npm install mysql

Comment: No, your code is missing an ending single quote and comma for the user field.